# JQuery data is not passed in the ajax post request, Hence get 415 Unsupported Media Type status code

Tags: jquery, ajax, iis-7, openrasta

I am trying to make a call to an api (post) via jquery, but the jquery call does not pass any data to the api and hence it fails by sending a response with status code 415 Unsupported Media Type. I have pasted the jquery code below. Am I missing something?

login: function () {

```
    var authData = {
        "UserName": $("#email").val(),
        "Password": $("#pass").val()
    };

    var url = apiUrl() + '/sessiontoken';

    $.ajax(url, {
        type: "post",
        data: JSON.stringify(authData),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
        beforeSend: function (xhr) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
        }
    });
    return false;

}
```

The url was returning 404 status from rest console.
Corrected the url and everthing is working fine now.

Answer (score 1):

Your ajax settings is wrong because you have opened `{` at wrong place. It should be like below. Also, since you are posting to another domain (cross domain request), set `crossDomain: true` in ajax settings:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: "post",
    crossDomain: true,
    data: JSON.stringify(authData),
    success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
    beforeSend: function (xhr) {
        xhr.setRequestHeader("accept", "application/json");
        xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    }
});
```

Comment: @sham - try this solution

Comment: This does not help.I do not get any javascript errors. I am trying to post data from one domain to another. I am using CORS and Rest API call for this.

Comment: `post data from one domain to another` - you need to look at `crossDomain: true` in ajax settings

Comment: post an answer with the correct working solution, so it'll be useful for others in future